# GDB / "malloc_error_break" not defined

Tags: c, macos, memory, gdb, malloc

I'm trying to learn more about malloc & free, so I've created a dylib that implements those functions, and I'm loading into a common system binary. However, it has bugs and I'm trying to debug them.

- malloc.dylib is my dynamic library

Here's the gdb output:

```
(gdb) set env DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES malloc.dylib
(gdb) break malloc_error_break
Function "malloc_error_break" not defined.
Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n]) n 
(gdb) r
Starting program: /bin/ls 
[+] init()
[-] myMalloc requesting: 4096 bytes
[-] memory address: 200000
bash(2035) malloc: *** error for object 0x200000: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

Program terminated with signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
The program no longer exists.
(gdb)
```

What I'm confused about is the message

```
Function "malloc_error_break" not defined.
```

When I try to set a breakpoint on it. Clearly, it's not breaking because it's unknown.

Any help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you can't set a breakpoint on `malloc_error_break` is that this function is defined in a shared library which has *not* been loaded yet.

You should be able to set the breakpoint after you run the program once.

Alternatively, use `start` instead of `run`, and when the program stops on `main`, you should *then* be able to set the breakpoint on `malloc_error_break`.